# Nextjs: API route accessible only from the server (SSR)

Tags: next.js

I have an api route `/get-data` which by default is open to public.

I want to return data from this endpoint (data I get from a paid external service) only if the server itself (SSR page) is requesting the data.

This is to prevent the external service abuse, where I have only 2000 request per month.

Is there any way to do it?
Maybe detecting in the api `req` object if the request is coming from the same server or from a browser...

Probably is impossible to make the `/get-data` route private, but for sure I can return an empty data object, an error or something if the request is not coming from the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin:
You have `page > your API /get-data > external API`

You make all your requests logic in `your API /get-data` and not on the page.

What you can do in your `/get-data API`:

A. You can secure your API route.

- You have a lot of tools and services such as [Auth0 SDK](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries) to secure your pages and API routes according to your roles or permissions
- You can set up a password, stored in `.env` [file](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables), generated by you. For example:

  ```
  //inside SSR page
  await fetch(`your_base_path/api/get-data?password=your_password`)

  //your api code
  if (process.env.password == req.query.password){
    //your code with accessing external API
    //I recommend you to save all incoming request to track where and when requests are coming.
  }
  else{
   //you can return your empty object here
   res.status(401)
  }
  ```

B. You can check your current limit of monthly requests by saving each request in your DB and checking the number of requests before contacting an external API.

C. You can track the IPs of requests with [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-ip) and save them. (For example to block after you see someone is making a lot of requests you don't like)

D: (advanced) you can develop your logic to generate access tokens for your API route. For example, you can create API route `/generate-token` and generate token based on your parameters.

Example:

Every time your SSR page triggered, your code

- generates the token based on your parameters (route, time, user etc.) by sending data from the page to `/generate-token`
- once token is generated you call your await fetch(`your_base_path/api/get-data?password=your_token_generated`) on your page, with your recently generated token.
- you validate your token in `/get-data`

*Notice: don't give access by IP, because IP of your server may differ (for example, in vercel) so the IP address is not a robust validation parameter.*

P.S. You can develop your logic for  your question, but the most important thing is to develop your logic in `/get-data` and not on the page. Also, once you have defined your `.env` variable, don't forget to add your env variable to your server.

Comment: You can replace API routes /generate-token with classes and make logic inside class functions after calling these functions. This case will be useful if you don't like someone generates tokens externally.
P.S. make `post` request instead of `get` request in A example

Comment: According to the documentation: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction

API Routes do not specify CORS headers, meaning they are same-origin only by default. Nevertheless my API is public as well by default which is a bit confusing and I may need to add a CORS middleware.